# Frequency of characters in a string that are not part of the string.

Tags: c, string

I am required to print the frequency of characters in a string, and I have developed a code for it. However, my code will just display the characters that are part of the string. But I want it to display all of the characters from a to z
for example:

```
hello.
A    0
B    0
C    0
D    0
E    1
```

and so on.

Anyhow, this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char string[100];
    int index, frequency[256] = {0};
    printf("Enter a String\n");
    fgets(string,99,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    for(index=0; string[index] != '\0'; index++){
        frequency[string[index]]++;
    }

    printf("\nCharacter   Frequency\n");
    for(index=0; index < 256; index++){
        if(frequency[index] != 0){
            printf("%5c%10d\n", index, frequency[index]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Don't use _magic numbers_!

Comment: `char` --> `unsigned char`. Then second loop, `for(index='a'; index < 'z'; index++){`

Comment: Why does code contain `if(frequency[index] != 0){`?

Comment: even if fflush(stdin) worked, - which it doesn't - fgets already has cleared stdin for you.

Comment: check out the function isalpha() to determine whether a character is A-Z/a-z use toupper() to convert to upper case then add to your frequency array, seems no point in adding characters outside that range.

Comment: @AndersK. "_fgets already has cleared stdin for you._" -- What if the input is  greater than 99 characters?

Comment: @CoolGuy well then it is not cleared but since he doesnt do any additional reading from the keyboard it is still unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to print the frequency for every character (including 0-frequency characters), you should not do this: `if(frequency[index] != 0)`.

If you take that line out, your code will print *every* character in the extended ASCII code, along with its frequency. As you have asked, you only need to know the frequencies for all the characters between *a* and *z*, and probably from *A* and *Z* also (I guess you do not need to know how many *TABs* are in your string, for instance).

To do this, you should replace the conditional statement in your final `for` loop with something like this:

```
if(('A' <= index && index <= 'Z') || ('a' <= index && index <='z'))
    printf("%5c%10d\n", index, frequency[index]);
```

As Sourav Ghosh pointed out, you should also replace `char` with `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(frequency[index] != 0){
        printf("%5c%10d\n", index, frequency[index]);
    }
```

You are specifically only printing the counts of characters that appear in your string at least once.  If you don't want to do that, then don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

This question is so similar to what is asked in Exercise 1.14 of KnR C. Below is a slightly modified version of my Exercise1.14 answer, which would the trick for you.

Output of the code is

```
~/code/KnR/Exercise/Chapter1 % clang a.c             
~/code/KnR/Exercise/Chapter1 % echo "hello" | ./a.out
'a' -   0.00% - 
'b' -   0.00% - 
'c' -   0.00% - 
'd' -   0.00% - 
'e' -  20.00% - ####################
'f' -   0.00% - 
'g' -   0.00% - 
'h' -  20.00% - ####################
'i' -   0.00% - 
'j' -   0.00% - 
'k' -   0.00% - 
'l' -  40.00% - ########################################
'm' -   0.00% - 
'n' -   0.00% - 
'o' -  20.00% - ####################
'p' -   0.00% - 
'q' -   0.00% - 
'r' -   0.00% - 
's' -   0.00% - 
't' -   0.00% - 
'u' -   0.00% - 
'v' -   0.00% - 
'w' -   0.00% - 
'x' -   0.00% - 
'y' -   0.00% - 
~/code/KnR/Exercise/Chapter1 %
```

Below is the code. It exploits the fact that each character is an int, and makes use of this fact. The code works for lowercase characters though (can be modified)

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* modified version of KnR Exercise 1.14 */
#define LOCHAR  97  /* first lowercase character */
#define HICHAR  122 /* last lowercase character */
#define SYM     '#' /* symbol to be used in the histogram */
#define MAX     50  /* value that corresponds to 100% */

int main(){
    int c, i;
    float nc, freq;
    int chars[HICHAR - LOCHAR];

    /* Initialize the array */
    for (i = 0; i < (HICHAR - LOCHAR); ++i)
        chars[i]=0;

    nc = freq = 0.0; /* total number of characters */

    /* read the input */
    while ((c=getchar()) != EOF ){
        if (c >= LOCHAR && c <= HICHAR){
            ++chars[c - LOCHAR];
            ++nc;
        }
    }

    /* print the histogram */
    for (c = 0; c < (HICHAR - LOCHAR); ++c){
        freq = ((chars[c] / nc) * 100.0);
        printf("'%c' - %6.2f%% - ",(c + LOCHAR), freq);

        for (i = 0; i < freq; i++)
            putchar(SYM);

        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `if` statement

```
    if(frequency[index] != 0){
```

As it **excludes** characters that are not part of the string.

Note that the subsequent `printf()` will print also non-printable characters (ex. the ones in the range 0..31)